# How does reference translates to asm in gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, llvm

Is reference is compiled as usual pointer or it has other stuff behind?

And how does it differ in clang?

Comment: Why not make a simple test program, build it with different compilers, and look at the generated code?

Comment: It can differ in complicated situations

Comment: Sometimes it does not even need to exist in the generated code as the compiler can just treat it as an alias to the referenced item.

Comment: There's no single fixed way, depends on the situation and optimizer. Thinking about it, probably a bit more accurate answer is, that the reference on machine code level doesn't exist, so there's no point to ask how it is translated into it. Reference is C-level thing, it may be, that several internal steps of compilation would be possible to identify as "reference", but when the final machine code is produced, this information is not any more needed and it's very likely lost/damaged in one of the last steps of compilation + optimization.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a reference as an immutable pointer that is automatically de-referenced on usage.  This isn't what the C++ standard says, so you cannot rely on that being an actual implementation.

Practically speaking though, it likely to be what you see in many cases.
Take the following example in the case of parameter passing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function (int *const n){
    printf("%d",*n);
}

void function (int & n){
    printf("%d",n);
}

int main(){
    int n = 123;
    function(&n);
    function(n);
}
```

Both `gcc` and `clang` produce identical code for the functions without any optimizations enabled:

```
function(int*):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     esi, eax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
        nop
        leave
        ret
function(int&):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     esi, eax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
        nop
        leave
        ret
```

Answer (score 0):

> How does reference translates to asm in gcc?

In general: It depends.

To find that out in a specific case, you can test by reading the generated assembly.

> Is reference is compiled as usual pointer or it has other stuff behind?

The implementation of code using a reference is practically identical to one using a pointer to achieve identical indirection. How each are implemented, is not guaranteed by the standard, but there is no need for implementing them differently.

References only differ from pointers in the way that they are allowed to use by the rules of C++. Of course, because the rules are different, pointers can be used in a way that references can not. And in such case you cannot compare whether pointers generate the same assembly.

The limitations of a reference *might* make some optimizations easier, so there might be a difference, but such optimization would also have been *possible* with pointers, so there is no guarantee of different assembly output when using references instead of pointers.

> And how does it differ in clang?

In general: It depends.

Both compilers are bound by the same rules of the standard. They might generate identical assembly or different. How the generated assembly of particular version of one compiler differs (if at all) from the assembly generated by a particular version of another compiler, with particular compilation options for each, on particular processor architecture on particular operating system, in a particular use case of a reference, can be found by inspecting and comparing the generated  assembly in each particular case.